# Python LooseVersion corrupt list

Tags: python, distutils

I am puzzled with the following case which result in failing execution in python 2.7.10:

```
from distutils.version import LooseVersion

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, field1):
        self.field1 = field1

a_instance = A('A')
version_tag = LooseVersion('5.0.0')

test1 = ['a', 1, [2,3,4], version_tag, a_instance]

print 1 in test1                        # True

print a_instance in test1               # AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'version'

print test1.__contains__(a_instance)    # AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'version'
```

However this works:

```
test1 = ['a', 1, [2,3,4], a_instance, version_tag]

print 1 in test1                        # True

print a_instance in test1               # True

print test1.__contains__(a_instance)    # True
```

I know how to fix the issue on my side but I fail to understand why LooseVersion is affecting the "contain" test. Could anyone explain?

(By the way this is also the case with StrictVersion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be narrowed to

```
a_instance == version_tag
```

(`__contains__` has to compare every element until it finds a match)

Unfortunately *LooseVersion* just can't compare to other objects.

Comment: Not sure I understand: then why reversing the order of objects would work?

Comment: Because it doesn't continue if it finds a match.

Comment: From what I see this is because within `__cmp__` in LooserVersion it is assumed that the arguments are both derivative of Version.

Comment: Then shouldn't cmp return false if argument is not of expected type (Version)?

Comment: Well, yes. You can report it as a bug.